# How to find out what submit handler an HTML FORM has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using Chrome where pressing enter automatically submits a form.

I have two forms on different pages, and neither has a submit INPUT/BUTTON. Both forms have similar (text) inputs in them.

FORM 1 automatically submits its data when pressing enter. FORM 2 on the other hand doesn't. I have to find out why this happens. Is there a way to find out what submit handlers are there attached to the two forms?

`myForm.get(0).onsubmit` (using jQuery) returns `null` in both cases.

Or is there another way to debug this issue? (Chrome DevTools, etc)

Comment: Visual Event might help. (it's a bookmarklet, just google it.)

Comment: is there a <button> element in FORM 1? that could trigger a submit event on enter

Comment: None of the forms have a submit INPUT/BUTTON. Not even a button (without submit).

Comment: How about posting the HTML of your forms? or better yet a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @KevinB Visual Event Chrome extensions looks great and also works great on other Web sites (like SO). It does not show my anything on mine though. +1 because it is a "good to know" tool.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you had 2 forms __on the same page__ but only the first submits. That is apparently not the case? Do you not have access to the code for the form? How is the form added to your page?

Comment: The forms are on two different pages. But I have just found the problem. It is just yes another browser specific issue. Writing the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched the problem some more and the issue was around the FORMs having ONLY one text input.

FORM 1 has only one text input. FORM 2 has 2 text inputs. Therefore, in Chrome, FORM 1 will submit on `Enter`. I have already asked this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu).

So in my case, it is NOT a script that was adding submit handlers to the forms, but simply the browser specific implementation of forms. IE, for example does not behave like this.

PS: @KevinB It also makes sense why Visual Effects was not showing any handlers. Because there were none on the forms.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter it is always going to default to the first form.

if you wnat to submit the second form from script then you need:

document.forms[1].submit();

Comment: There some more to it. More details in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17797230/454103