# Why does a FORM with one text INPUT submit on enter while one with two text INPUTs does not?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have just found out that a FORM containing only one INPUT (not hidden) will automatically submit when pressing Enter.

But a form containing at least two INPUTS (not hidden) will NOT submit when pressing enter.

(None of the scripts have a submit/button/input[type=submit] inside)

Take a look at this [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/RV6cW/). Is there an explanation/standard for this behavior?

```
<form id="form1" method="POST">
    <p>Does submit:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="focus and press enter"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="POST">
    <p>Does <strong>not</strong> submit:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="does not submit"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: If you add an `input type=submit` to the 2nd form it will submit. I'm searching for the standard about it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This behaviour was introduced in the HTML 2.0 specification. See the following article for more details:

[Form submission and the ENTER key?](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/formquestion.html)

> When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the
>   user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit
>   the form

Source: [W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2)

Answer (score 4):

That's a browser specific implementation . . . some versions of IE actually does not do that by default, but Firefox and some of the other browsers saw fit to make the assumption that, for a form with one text box, the user (or page designer) will always want the form to submit on `Enter` from that field.

There have actually been multiple times that I have had to code around that . . . it's one of the more questionable browser design decisions in my opinion.

**Edit:**

There are more nuanced answers to your question, if you are interested . . . apparently different browsers (and their different versions) have different behaviors around this specific situation, including whether or not they submit at all, whether or not the `click` event occurs, etc.  I can provide links to more information if you would like to read more.

But the short answer is that, it actually is intentional, if not consistently supported across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following should work in IE.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input,select').keypress(function(event) { return event.keyCode != 13; }); 
  });
```