# How can I stop enter from submitting a form when it has only one enabled input without javascript

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, form-submit

I have a **google address entry** on a form.  There is only one enabled input - where the user types in the address.

If they select an entry from the **dropdown** with a mouse, everything works fine.  If they press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the google script does not populate the disabled address field **inputs** and the form is submitted.

I can see the reason here. [Why does a FORM with one text INPUT submit on enter while one with two text INPUTs does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu)

There are numerous **javascript** solutions.  Is there a way I can get around this without javascript; by placing some other html control on the form ?

Comment: why did you choose the google-maps-api-3 -tag for this question?

Comment: Do you really need a form? Why not just an input?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, because thats what I am using for the address entry.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, thats too simple.  If you put that as an answer I can tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrUpsidown said, don't use a form.  It is not necessary to have a form on an html page.  If there is no form, it can not be submitted.