# jQuery submit not triggered on ENTER keypress

Tags: jquery, html

a very simple FORM and JS:

```js
$('#gg').submit(function() {
    alert('s');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="gg" method="post">
    <input name="languageId" type="text">
    <input name="languageName" type="text">
</form>
```

.submit wont be triggered by pressing enter on an input somehow. But if I have one input, it does work!

Comment: Why should it ?

Comment: You need to place a `<button type="submit" />` or `<input type="submit" />` *within* the `form` for this behaviour to work

Comment: why should it not? I attached a submit event, didnt I?

Comment: you should also put a submit button inside your `form` tag.

Comment: No. you attached a submit event listener. The event has to occur for it to call the handler

Comment: You have nothing to call the submit event and only forms with a *single input* default to submitting on pressing enter.

Comment: @j08691 Has that always been the case? I never knew that one :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan lol yup. It's a verrry old 'feature'. Link coming...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu

Comment: Wow HTML 2. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 5):

Pressing the ENTER key will submit the form if you add a submit input to your form.

```js
    $('#gg').submit(function() {
        alert('s');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="gg" method="post">
    <input name="languageId" type="text"/>
    <input name="languageName" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: _"only if"_ Not true. Forms with a single text input will submit when pressing enter on the input.

Comment: @j08691 You are correct. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this is to manually setup the enter key press like this:

```
$('#gg input').keypress(function (e) { // listen to keypress on your input controls
    if (e.which == 13) {   // if enter key...
        $('#gg').submit(); // submit the form
    }
});
```

Here it is in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/8md75a6f/3/

Comment: really don't need the return false

Comment: I don't like this solution, or you have to change your selector. If OP have multiple forms the form #gg will be submitted for each forms

Comment: The answer from @RogerC is probably superior, but I'll leave this answer here in case in helps anyone else.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Or just change your selector to `$(formselector input)` in this case `$("#gg input")`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, adding a

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none;">
```

seems to solve everything